# Cursor return a null result after I call a Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I'm doing a  app that I need open a gallery and choose a pic, but when I return to the Activity the item's Cursor return null.

In here I open the gallery:

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private void abrirGaleria(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select a pic"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
```

in here I try get the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == ((Activity)ctx).RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            File filePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

            compartilharAFoto(filePath.getPath());
        }
    }

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        Cursor cursor = ((Activity)ctx).getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            //cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(0);//idx);
        }
    }
```

and the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:1633 flg=0x1 }} to activity {br.com.blacktoad.q48h2/br.com.blacktoad.q48h2.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

another error description that appears:

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Comment: It should be: `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {two statements} else {sorry no rows return null;}`. And use idx! Not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't have column you are trying to access.
Replace:

> ```
> Cursor cursor = ((Activity)ctx).getContentResolver()
> .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
> ```

with:

```
Cursor cursor =  ((Activity)ctx).getContentResolver()
.query(contentURI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null, null);
```

and update this line as follows:

```
 int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

and uncomment:

```
  cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: @user1697583 Please see updated answer. Column changed from `ImageColumns.Data` to `Media.Data`